# Is it possible to specify the range of data values in general database?

Tags: database, database-design, database-schema

I want to deal with some data of certain range in general database and predefine the range of every data item. The range of some are continuous, like a float number ranged from a minimum value to a maximum value,and the range of the others are discrete, like the nationality of people which could be US, Japan or Spain, a large but finite range of alternatives. This kind of schema is usually achieved in the business logic layer, and I want to know the if I can handle it in the database layer as well, especially in Non-SQL database.

Comment: Assuming I understand the question, I think you are looking for the `in` operator.

Comment: No, I just want to find a way to predefine the range of a certain data property in the database so that when I use the value that doesn't belong to the specified range,the database won't accept it.

Comment: please specify what database engine you are trying to use for more help.

Comment: Well, initially I didn't know if my problem can be solved in the database level so I didn't specify any engine. While if this can be done by some kind of database, I prefer using Non-SQL database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**At the time I wrote this answer the question was for databases in general, and not specific to Non-SQL databases.**

In many (relational) databases you can handle this using `check` constraints in the database that lets you define acceptable values using boolean expressions. This would apply to both insert and update statements.

An example that works with MSSQL and Postgresql:

```sql
create table t 
(
    -- country_code has to be a Nordic country.
    country_code varchar(20) check (country_code in ('NO','SE','DK', 'FI','IS')),

    -- float_value has to be in a certain range
    float_value float check (float_value between 0.01 and 0.05),

    -- int_value has to be in a range, and in steps of 5
    int_value int check ( (int_value between 10 and 50) and (int_value % 5 = 0) )
);

-- allowed
insert into t values ('SE', 0.03, 25);
-- not allowed as int_value is not divisible by 5
insert into t values ('SE', 0.03, 26);
-- disallowed due to country_code not in set
insert into t values ('US', 0.05, 25);
```

See [documentation for Postgresql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/ddl-constraints.html) for more information and examples.

Another option is to use triggers before or instead of inserts that lets you validate data and do more complex processing than check constraints would allow (like reference data in other tables). Triggers can be bad for performance though.

If you want to restrict the range of possible values to a predefined range you can also store those values in a table (like `countries(code, name)`) and use a `foreign key` constraint to ensure that it won't be possible to insert data that doesn't exist in the related domain table.

Comment: It seems to be what I expect. Is it still available now? Can I find an alternative solution if I use Non-relational database?

Comment: @Ivan814 What do you mean be _is it still available now?_ And while this type of check is a common feature in database, it would depend on the specific system if it's available or if there is something similar.

Comment: Because you mentioned that it's not supported in current database systems in your previous comment. I couldn't find it now.

Comment: @Ivan814 `check` constraints are a part of the SQL standard and supported in most of the major databases, MySQL/MariaDB being a notable exception.

Comment: I googled it and found it's used in SQL. How can I solve my problem if I use Non-SQL?

Comment: I think I misunderstood what your said in that comment, sorry for that.

Comment: Hi, @jpw, I'm still looking for the way to solve my problem with Non-SQL database, If I can't find one, I will try the way in your answer.

Comment: @Ivan814 With non SQL (or relational) databases, by which I guess you mean NoSQL databases like MongoDB, CouchDB, Neo4J and similar the way you constrain data input will depend on the specific product as there isn't really any standard for NoSQL databases in the way that there is for SQL databases. To be able to give you a more specific answer we need to know what database you are using. I would say that the question how you do it with a specific database is a different question than the one you posted that I answered which was more general in nature.

Comment: Currently I'm learning MongoDB, and I will probably learn HBase, Neo4j, Cassandra/DynamoDB and Oracle/DB2 in the next couple of month. At present I want to achieve my schema by MongoDB because I'm learning it.

Comment: @Ivan814 My answer covers the way to do it with relational databases, I would suggest you post another question on how to do it with MongoDB. Also, when you edited the question to make it Non-SQL specific you more or less made it a new question and invalidated my answer. Please don't do this, but ask a new question instead or changing it.